# JQuery Validate for Django Model Forms

Tags: jquery, django, forms, validation

I have looked over this documentation (http://streamhacker.com/2010/03/08/jquery-validation-django-forms/) for some help regarding form validation. In my forms.py I have the following:

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'language']
        widgets = {
            'language': forms.RadioSelect(attrs={
                'class':'{required:true}'
            }),
        }
```

So for the language field, I want to serve it as a `RadioButton` field and I want to make it a required field. So if the user leaves this field empty, then a warning would pop up. Here is my models.py where I defined the `language` column:

```
LANGUAGE = (('AR', 'Arabic'), ('FR', 'French'), ('ES', 'Spanish'))
language = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=LANGUAGE)
```

Anyways, no warnings pop up when I submit the form even with the `language` field empty. Any ideas?

Comment: Just do
    language = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=LANGUAGE, required = True)

Comment: widget overrides that `required` attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply changed it to the following:

```
'language': forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'required': True}),
```